# Python - sqlite exception "Error near s" - Is my sqlite statement incorrect?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I currently have a sqlite statement that looks like this in the debugger

```
'SELECT id FROM ITable where question=\\'Is your child\\'s serial correct?\\''
```

this is the code

```
def TestStatement(question,patient_id,student_id):
    try:
        str = "SELECT id FROM ITable where question='%s' " %(question)
        r = executeSelect(str) #<<--------Exception occurs here
    except Exception as e:
        return "Exception Occured"
    return r
```

The question parameter is:

```
'Is your child\\'s serial correct?'
```

The exception returned is:

```
near "s": syntax error
```

I cannot modify the question parameter. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ? or why this sql statement is incorrect ?

Comment: if you need extra `\ ` before `\'` then use `\\\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is - *you are using string formatting to construct your query* - this not only dangerous (see [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)), but also leads to problems with Python-to-database type conversions and quotes (which is exactly what you have in this case).

Instead, omit the quotes and use a *parameterized query*:

```
query = "SELECT id FROM ITable where question = ?"
cursor.execute(query, (question, ))
```

Note: you would probably need to adjust your `executeSelect()` function to accept parameters in separate argument(s).

Comment: I still dont see why quotes are having a issue here. Is it because of the word `child's` ?

Comment: @Murphy316 yeah, exactly, as a result you have *unbalanced quotes* and a syntactically wrong query. Sorry for not saying that explicitly. Thanks.

Comment: I get the error "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: @Murphy316 you probably left the `%(question)` part somewhere..

Comment: Thsi is what i have  `str = "SELECT id FROM .... where question=?"
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        r = cursor.execute(str, (question,))`

Comment: @Murphy316 interesting, on which line does it fail? Also, what if you would replace `?` with `%s` (no quotes)? Thanks.

Comment: Its working now thanks